# Can we send a tuple as an argument to sys.exit() in python

Tags: python

I am running my scripts on python 2.6. The requirement is as mentioned below.

There are some 100 test scripts (all python scripts) in one directory. I have to create one master python script which will start running all the 100 test scripts one by one and then I have to display whether test case is failed or not. Every script will call `sys.exit()` to finish the execution of script. Currently I am reading the `sys.exit()` value from the master script and I am determining whether the particular test case is failed or not.

But now there is a requirement change that I have to display the log file name also (log files will be created when I run scripts). So can I send a tuple as argument (which contains status as well as log file name) to `sys.exit()` instead of sending integer value?

I have read on net that if we pass an argument other than integer, `None` is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is printed to `stderr` and results in an exit code of 1. So if I pass a tuple as an argument, will `os` consider as failure even in success case also as I am not passing `None`?

I am using `subprocess.popen()` in my master script to run the scripts and I am using `format()` to read the `sys.exit()` value.

Comment: A UNIX process's exit status is a single-byte integer value. Even if you passed anything else, it couldn't be used as exit status.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Python [allows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) you to pass _any_ object to `sys.exit` so that you can also pass, e.g., strings to conveniently set an error message to be printed to `stderr`. It coerces non-integer objects to exit status 1.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, ...a statement which in no way contradicts what I said.

Comment: I guess I'm not reading this question the same way as others. "Can I send `sys.exit` a tuple containing status as well as other values instead of an integer?" Yes. "If I pass a tuple as an argument, will the os consider as failure?" Yes. But if the status code is in the tuple and you are reading it, what's the problem? If the question is can you pass `sys.exit` a non-integer argument, the answer is **yes** not **no**.

Comment: For the record, the point of `sys.exit` allowing (and printing) non-integer arguments is to allow a subsystem to *propose* an error message that will be automatically printed if no caller catches the `SystemExit` exception.  Any other use is madness that should be replaces with explicit use of `sys.stderr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot. `sys.exit()` sets the process exit code, and that's it. There are no provisions for processes to do anything other with that code but set it to an integer.

You *can* write data to `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`, and your master script can *read* from those streams.

Certainly, if you pass any other kind of object (apart from `None` or an integer) to `sys.exit()` it'll write that as a string to `sys.stderr` for you, but in that case the exit code is *always* going to be set to `1`; you no longer have control over the exit status. Better to set the exit status explicitly, after writing to an output stream explicitly.

Just use the [`subprocess.Popen()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), setting either `stdout` or `stderr` to `subprocess.PIPE`, and then use the [`Popen.communicate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to read the data from that piped stream:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([executable, arg1, arg2],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
status_code = proc.returncode
```

Comment: While I agree this is probably the _right_ way to do it, your answer kind of makes it sound like you can't give `sys.exit()` anything but an integer, which is contrary to [what the docs say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit). Can you explain?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, as the docs say, a non-integer object isn't used as process exit status, but is printed to stderr (after which `1` is used as exit status).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Expanded on my answer there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I saw. I think this is clearer. I guess my question is whether or not the 1 exit status actually matters. If it's in the tuple and it's being read by OP's code (which may not need to interact with other Unix-y things), would using something besides `sys.exit(0)` or `sys.exit(None)` actually cause breakage?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Yes, if turning the object into a string raises an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. Passing a tuple will print the tuple to stderr and return with a exit code of 1. You must return None to denote success.

Notice this is a convention of shells and the like and is not *required.* That being said the conventions are in place for a very, very good reason.